# C'mon now - someone is having a joke! Who up voted this?

Tags: discussion, review, up-votes, not-an-answer, review-abuse

While going through the review queue I spotted [something extraordinary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13489018/109702).

Can someone trace where this answer has been so that we can find how it got three up votes by the time I saw it? Has it possibly been through multiple review queues?

For those who don't have 10K and won't be able to see it once it gets deleted, this is the answer (on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324062/eclipse-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-between-consoles)):

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAu4Q.png]

I know it will be goneburger soon enough, but is it at all possible to give anyone the electronic slapping for their part in this?

Comment: Robot reviewers... how I despise them...

Comment: Now at -1 - 20k+ users will be able to vote to delete.

Comment: We really need a catchy word for those people! What about Roborovers? The main problem is those approving mindlessly and carelessly, but upvoting just for fun is just as bad or maybe even worse as it can't be undone.

Comment: @Sha, `roborovers` is too cute. How about `review drones`?

Comment: How about *Waste of Space*.

Comment: it is maybe even funnier that top-voted, accepted, +500 bountied [link-only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3333728/839601) now points to **dead site** martialjava (dropped more than a year ago, according to [tools4domains](http://www.tools4domains.com/dropping_domains/09-27-2011/martialjava.com))

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Taking action to improve First Posts and Late Answers reviewing - Upvote is too easy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155299/165773)

Comment: @gnat to make it worse, the author (who probably wrote the plugin) is ignoring the comments.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd well, stuff like that has been eloquently covered by Gilles [long time ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116360/165773 "here") - **"...If a question has an accepted answer which consists solely of a link, this sends the wrong message, especially after the link breaks. Sure, the accepted answer might have helped the asker, but it's not going to help future visitors, and the community should not be penalized for that answerer or asker's failing..."**

Comment: This happens frequently. There was an example in chat lately of an auto-generated spam answer with *absolutely no coherent sentence at all* that got three upvotes as well

Comment: Found it, it was 2 upvotes: [Whats the most important part of html page in terms of SEO keyword targeting- the title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639803/6483806#6483806) it's hilarious.

Comment: That is nothing, at least you can make sense of this post. How about the robot-upvotes for these two gems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6483806 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6483973. Tell me what the poster there is trying to say. *I say it's context-free grammar generated text, meant to _look_ like real text, by a failed spambot.*

Comment: @Pekka: The 3rd upvote is for that bot's *other* post.

Comment: I know I'm late, but, slugster, that is in no way "something extraordinary" anymore. It's almost the norm.

Comment: It looks like this answer appeared both in the Late Answers and First Posts review queues. It was reviewed by four people, with one set of reviews here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1051884 and another here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/1051885 . Whenever I see something weird like this, I always search back through the history of those queues (I don't think you can spam upvotes in the Low Quality Posts queue).

Comment: ...and before people lynch these reviewers, I should point out that both Artemix and Alexis Pigeon did the right thing and flagged this as not being an answer as soon as they saw it. There might also be other reviewers involved here, if I'm missing a queue somewhere.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I call them review monkeys.

Comment: @BradLarson these guys you mentioned, those who flagged, are the same who upvoted? (i for one down-voted and flagged, although that wasn't from the queue:)

Comment: @gnat - We can't know for certain who upvoted the answer, merely who reviewed it. I do know that the two people I mention flagged it as soon as they reviewed, so I doubt they voted for it.

Comment: @BradLarson I see, thanks. For a second I thought you meant flaggers and upvoters are the same, quickly figured it's very unlikely but decided to double-check with you

Comment: @Brad Larson: Thanks. Will lynch them anyway.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Makes you wonder why people are posting about these only now... I'm guessing the point is to tell us how numbingly commonplace this pattern of behavior has become?

Comment: I've seen this several times JSF/JSF2 tags as well. Answers from new users were upvoted relatively extremely a lot, usually up to 3 votes. However this is more than often completely contradicting other answers on the same question, which are usually already accepted and usually have only 0 or 1 or maybe 2 votes in those "niche" tags. This is very disturbing and confusing. Answers from new users are voted without viewing them in the full context. [Again, the /review is severely broken. There are way too much monkeys in there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149621).

Comment: Could that be one of the fake review items mentioned in http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/11/se-podcast-37/ in the third bullet point? If so, it has catched three roborevs...

Comment: @Chichiray - the issue there is not showing the whole context which is wh I don't do many reviews on the first posts and late answers ans has been pointed out on other meta questions there needs to be something other than  upvote to remove the question from your queue as well as showing the context ie all answers