# Why do people upvote obvious non-answers?

Tags: discussion, review, up-votes, not-an-answer, review-abuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C’mon now - someone is having a joke! Who up voted this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156343/cmon-now-someone-is-having-a-joke-who-up-voted-this)

I just came upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508508/507519). It is *obviously* not an answer - what with the poster mentioning a bunch of thing that they *cannot* do and the final request for assistance. Yet I was surprised to see that it had *two* upvotes, especially considering that the question itself had none.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AmiN.png]

Why would people vote for an obvious non-answer? Is it inexperienced users that misunderstand the vote system for something along the lines of YouTube's like/dislike or Google's `+1` - or maybe for a forum-style *"me too!"* ? Or is it something else?

And, most importantly, should we do something about it?

Comment: Most probably to gain the shiny [review badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges).

Comment: Robot reviewers to gain gold badge.

Comment: Hm, interesting... I can *delete* my question, but not *close* it single-handedly. Weird...

Comment: No need to delete. It may help future users to find duplicate question by keyword of this question.

Comment: I did search for duplicates, I swear :-) I guess the title of that other question was a bit too lively (?) for me...

Comment: @hims056: I was trying to close it, not delete it - hence the comment :-)

Comment: @thkala: Ahh.. Didn't note that. :)