# This audit looks completely obvious. Is it really needed?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

[image]

Has the AI developed a sense of humour now ?

Does such an audit serve any purpose ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was I told, "Congratulations, this was only a test" when reviewing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/why-was-i-told-congratulations-this-was-only-a-test-when-reviewing)

Comment: @AshRj You'd be surprised.

Comment: I remember seeing that particular post a long time ago, before we got "Congratulations!" messages and the only way you knew was the fact that clicking Recommend Deletion didn't bring up any dialog menu. ;P

Comment: @AnnaLear Now, you have to be kidding :)

Comment: Please see my question http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156938/169404

Comment: You might want to check out [the review-abuse tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-abuse). One example after another of completely ridiculous reviews.

Comment: related: [C'mon now - someone is having a joke! Who up voted this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156343/165773), 3 (**three**) upvotes given to the blatant [meta-tag:not-an-answer] that says _The link seems to be not working. Can you please share a working link._

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O ye of little faith. :)

[image]

And lest you think the upvote was deserved before the answer was edited and deleted, here's the original revision:

[image]

Some people will upvote **anything**.

Comment: That is unbelievable O.o

Comment: @AshRj This did turn out to be a surprisingly good example of why we need audits. :)

Comment: Yes, and my faith in this system is restored ;)

Comment: It could simply be, that the guy who upvoted, had a **Mulberry Backpack Bag** ;)