# Why is this a bad post?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review trap shows post that was bad, after it has been edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157659/review-trap-shows-post-that-was-bad-after-it-has-been-edited)

I was reviewing some answers and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts#first-posts/1145341?&_suid=135489288495408145462528003329) came up. I thought it was a well written first post that provided details, a link, and answered the question (how to fix the missing table).

I was going to upvote it, but the audit message (this was an audit and **you didn't pass**) popped up and told me I was wrong. I doesn't understand what about this answer is so bad... It seems (from the comments) that it was a link only answer, but it was edited and there's lots of detail now.

Is this a case where the audit message shouldn't have come up due to the edit made on the post, or am I in the wrong thinking this is a good post?

If it's the ladder, can you please help me understand what's wrong with it?

Comment: I believe that the bad answer criteria is based on what the post contained when it was originally flagged. I think that this is being looked into though (Can't find a link about it being looked into but I think I seen it mentioned somewhere)

Comment: Submitted as a bug [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157659/review-trap-shows-post-that-was-bad-after-it-has-been-edited).

Comment: If it's a ladder, what's wrong with it is that it doesn't have any rungs and you can't climb it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original version of this answer was basically just a link (see my comment at the bottom of the answer, and the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13594153/revisions).)

As Ren alludes to, this seems to be a little bit of a bug in the honeypots; It is considering primarily that the post has some flagging/deletion action on it, without considering if the post has been edited since then. By what was visible now, you were right in how you reviewed.

Don't worry too much about it; a miscue here and there won't be a big deal, and I'm sure this will be addressed soonish.

(Edit: Kudos to [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson) for the clarification)

Comment: It's not so much of a case of "taking the original version" as it is just looking for posts which have a deletion event caused by flagging and then displaying them normally. It's not checking if they've been edited, just assuming they're still the same thing.

Comment: @animuson Oh, good point! Editing...