# What happens when post older than 60 days scored +3 or higher is deleted by 6 "No Comment" recommendations?

Tags: discussion, review, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

As far as I understand, it is possible for post scored +3 or higher to land in Low Quality queue and be deleted by 6 "No Comment" recommendations.

Besides a [record in post history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/165773), what happens in this case? As far as I understand,

- moderators can't find about this since system doesn't raise a flag for their attention
- authors can't find it out since there's neither [inbox notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197543/low-quality-but-looks-salvageable-trying-to-pick-between-looks-good-and-re/197568#comment625482_197568), nor [reputation change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124754/165773) that could be visible in profile, nor is it listed in [Recent Deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/165773) in their profile
- deleted post is added to the list of recently deleted in [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools) page

Is my understanding correct? Is there something worth worrying about in this process?

---

<sub>For the sake of completeness, same seems to be happening to old posts without votes at all, or those having zero reputation "balance" due to up/down votes split. I don't ask about these because I don't even know whether there is a reason to worry about deletion of higher voted posts.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As far as I understand, it is possible for post scored +3 or higher to land in Low Quality queue and be deleted by 6 "No Comment" recommendations.

Nope. If a post scores > 0 and the folks reviewing it say it should be deleted, then a new flag is immediately raised. A moderator will need to step in and decide who is correct: the folks who up-voted the post, or the folks who say it is worthless.

Should the moderator handling the flag decide that it *should* be deleted, they of course have the option to also leave a comment describing *why* it should be deleted, and the author of the post will be notified of this comment.

Note that this behavior [changed very recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue) - prior to that change, posts scoring > 0 would either hang around in the queue collecting ever-more reviews until folks either down-voted it enough to be deleted, or it collected enough "Looks Good" reviews to be dismissed.

Comment: looks like a decent design