# Don't use very old posts for audits

Tags: support, review-audits

I just [failed a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3033613) by attempting to comment on an answer the system considered excellent. I thought it was fine, not great and was going to add a comment asking for a little more context in the answer.

Now this answer has 17 upvotes; which is why the system thought it was excellent. But this was way back in 2010, and as we keep telling everyone; standards have changed since then and things that might have received upvotes in the past might be closed/down voted today (in my opinion I think this would have stuck around at 0 if posted today)

I would like to propose that questions/answers are only used for audits if they are (say) less that 1 year old.

Comment: Some may say this is "I've failed a test; therefore the test is wrong" thinking. To those people I say; "You think I am bad, therefore your thinking is wrong"

Comment: Related, or at least very similar: [What an audit!? Would you fail?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197632/what-an-audit-would-you-fail)

Comment: Why would adding a comment even be considered failing the audit? Why aren't you allowed to comment on a good post?

Comment: @sth I'm enclined to agree but apparently robo reviewers were using add comment as a catch all pass

Comment: @sth this is virtual identical to a discussion we were having yesterday.  In an effort to keep robo-reviewers from gaming the system, you have ended up in a system where the actual steps to pass an audit are not consistent with appropriate behavior because typical appropriate behavior might be used as a catchall for robo reviewers to pass all audits.  Basically we've created a review system that is so easy to game that you need to create somewhat illogical rules in order to keep them from gaming the system.

Comment: (and even if a post is under a year old or what have you, let us automatically dispute them)

Comment: @RichardTingle I would like to point out that the given answer was not very old. It was posted a few days ago on September 10, 2013. Perhaps you confused the Sep 10 with September 2010?

Comment: @JoshuaDwire That I did, that I did. I'm not entirely sure what to do now. I still stand by everything I said but i've lost my example

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Assuming its not already the case that old posts can't be audits

Comment: @RichardTingle I'm pretty sure old posts can't be audits.  I was questioning that when I saw your question originally, but I got distracted by work before I asked about it....  I know for a fact that the current criteria for close/reopen audits state that the post must be new.  Less sure about FP, LA and LQ, but I seem to recall seing that somewhere that they should be newish posts.

Comment: @psubsee That is good, I misread the date in this case, voting to close

Comment: @psubsee2003: It's just stupid that the much more harmful and much harder to detect action of upvoting makes you pass those audits. And that while chances are high that the reviewer doesn't have the expertise to judge correctness of the answer, and therefore *shouldn't upvote at all*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by [Joshua](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198877/dont-use-very-old-posts-for-audits#comment631073_198877), the post in question is from September 10, 2013, not Sept 2010, so your example question is not a good fit

---

The current criteria for close/reopen audits, as defined by [Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/182513), clearly state that audits for those queues will not include old posts.  The exact criteria was not published in that post, but it specifically says "Recently posted".

[Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198877/dont-use-very-old-posts-for-audits#comment631103_198919) has confirmed in the comments below, the criteria for all posts specifically require all audit candidates posted within the last 30 days, but that could changed if/when the audit selection criteria are changed.

Comment: The criteria for first post / late answer and low quality audits are considerably more simple than close/reopen audits (and also subtly different). That said, ALL audit posts are limited to things posted in the past 30 days (for now, at least).

Comment: @Shog9 as far as I can tell per recent complaints at MSO this limitation of past 30 days is now [broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388914/should-this-partial-answer-be-an-audit-in-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue#comment769808_388919). And I mean broken and not just somehow reasonably softened, system now pushes 8 years old posts as audits, go figure

Comment: That's... Terrifying. @gnat