# Close vote review audit with an actual close vote on it

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, review-audits

I was under the impression that questions with real close votes aren't used for "known good" review audits.

I just [failed a close vote review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4104346) for looking for a duplicate, when in fact the audit question had
**[a real duplicate vote on it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497976/why-filtering-an-unsorted-list-is-faster-than-filtering-a-sorted-list#comment32452528_21497976)** To further add to the issue I was using the filter feature to look for duplicates at the time, as in:  filter duplicate; [css].

I know it has been discussed many times before, but the audit behavior for duplicates just [doesn't work to begin with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote). Adding the possibility of audits being selected from questions with real close votes makes the whole thing really irritating and obviously flawed.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: It didn't have any close votes on it. It had a **recommend closure** flag on it. The system apparently doesn't pay attention to flags.

Comment: @animuson My guess, without actual knowledge, is that it only pays attention to "helpful" flags.  Those flags are likely still pending, or declined/disputed.

Comment: I closed the question, since it's clearly a duplicate.

Comment: @Oded I think the [bug] vs. [support] tagging may be up for debate here... Is what I'm seeing really the intended behavior?

Comment: @apaul34208 If the question actually did have close votes on it, then yes, it'd be a bug.  But it didn't.

Comment: @Servy Does that really mean it is working properly?

Comment: @apaul34208 It means that if you think it's not working as well as you would like, changing it would be a [meta-tag:feature-request].  Understanding *what* it does, or why it does it, would be a [meta-tag:support] question.  Oded interpreted your question as the latter.  If, based on the answer you get, you think it should change, then a feature request could be in order.

Comment: @Servy I get your point. Just feels like: "Its not a bug its a feature..."

Comment: @apaul34208 - the feature is working as intended, so it isn't a software bug. If you feel that the feature should be changed, by all means, make this a feature request.

Comment: related: [Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773) My overall feeling is, idea of overly automated audit selection is a bit... weird, softly speaking. Quite a pity that [SE team doesn't care](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168374/165773)

Answer (score 2):

It does **not** have an actual close vote on it! You think so because it has a comment, but that comment is posted by someone that doesn't have 3k rep, and so it is not a close vote.

It is a duplicate, anyway. But probably the question was good enough to be picked by the audit system.

Comment: It did get a close *flag* though (two, in fact).

Comment: @Servy: Probably the audit system doesn't look at the flag count of the question.

Comment: @ProgramFOX perhaps it should

Comment: @JanDvorak [It should probably only look at *helpful* flags though.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222075/close-vote-review-audit-with-an-actual-close-vote-on-it#comment721737_222075)  I assume, without actually knowing, that that's what it does now.  If not, that's what I'd like to see, and these flags here *weren't* helpful at the time of the audit.

Comment: @Servy what about helpful _or_ pending flags? Declined flags are fair game, I guess

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm on the fence there.  I could see it either way.

Comment: @Servy it's really bad when a question with a valid dupe comment is "known" not to be a duplicate