# A question I voted to close is presented to me as a review audit

Tags: feature-request, bug, vote-to-close, review-audits

I just encountered [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4915976?filter-closereason=opinionbased).

As you can see, I am one of the people who voted to close this question in the first place, and the question hasn't been edited.

This seems wrong to me. While audits are meant to be easy, this is just giving things away. It's not testing if I'm paying attention. At best, it's only testing if I haven't changed my mind.

I believe this should be addressed - the CV queue should not use questions that you have VTC'd yourself as audits. Unless the question has been edited, reopened and closed since.

Comment: You paid enough attention to notice you closed the question before. Yay, you are not a robo reviewer, mission accomplished!

Comment: heh, it can be even worse than that: [Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773)