# Should close vote audits include questions that I closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, review-audits

I just got [this reopen audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/reopen/349095), on a question I closed:

[image]

Surely it would be sensible to not give audits of questions to the close voters?

Comment: same case in close queue: [A question I voted to close is presented to me as a review audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232257/a-question-i-voted-to-close-is-presented-to-me-as-a-review-audit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for you to be able to realize that you've already acted on that question you'll have had to be paying enough attention to the content.  The whole point of the audit is to make sure that you're paying attention, so it has succeeded in doing its job *even if you've already acted on that post outside of /review*.

Comment: This was a reopen queue though - but it wasn't because of an edit, it was just there...

Comment: @Tim It wouldn't matter which queue this is, or what action is being tested.

Comment: Okay :) Thanks for pointing that out!