# Don't allow honeypots for questions that I've voted on, or that I've already passed an audit on

Tags: feature-request, review, voting, review-audits

When reviewing, it has happened that I get a review-audit for a [question I've already voted on](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/104434) (this is not the first time, it is only the most recent).

If I know I've upvoted a question, and I know that the question has very positive score, doesn't that defeat the purpose of a [honeypot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152709/improving-the-quality-of-reviews-project-honeypot)? If the honeypot is simply to ensure that I'm paying attention, then I suppose it doesn't matter, but if it's also trying to ensure that I do the **correct** thing, then it shouldn't be a question that I might recognize.

A second, related request is not to give review audits for a question that I've already audited.

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/100258
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/104511

This can't be desired behavior.

Edit: Today, I got an audit for a question I had voted to close already. This is also not desired behavior!

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/106513

Here's a [new one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/120719):

[image: Review Audit]

Comment: related: [Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773)