# Don't give me known good audits on questions I've down voted

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I came across a 'known good' audit in the Low Quality Posts review.

> [image: the audit]

When I saw it, I was "I'm sure I've seen this before..."

> [image: the question]

Yep.  Sure enough, I had.  And I had down voted it.

> [image]

I haven't cast a close vote on it because there were other more pressing questions (I'm out of close votes for the day) and I want to think more about it.

So, please don't show me "known good" questions that I've cast down votes on. I've already stated (with my vote) that I don't think its good. Trying to compel me to click 'looks OK' goes against my sensibilities. I just might have had some close votes to cast and had made up my mind on the question.

Comment: related: [Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773)